# NoClassDefFoundError for ComposeView in Java project using Kotlin library with Jetpack Compose and Material 3

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on an Android project in Java that uses a Kotlin library incorporating Jetpack Compose and Material 3. When I try to run the app, I encounter a NoClassDefFoundError related to androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView. The error occurs at the line where ComponentActivity.setContent is called in the Kotlin library. Here's the relevant part of the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/ui/platform/ComposeView;
    at androidx.activity.compose.ComponentActivityKt.setContent(ComponentActivity.kt:55)
    ...
```

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio, and enabling multi-dex, but none of these solutions have resolved the issue.

I've also tried and manually add the dependencies manually to the Java project.

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.6.2")
```

Any idea on what could be causing this issue and how would I go about solving it?

PS: As a side note, the library published to maven central's snapshot repository has the compose dependencies listed in the pox.xml file but they aren't being fetched unless I mention them manually in my Java project.

Comment: Do you also have dependency on activity compose `androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2`?

Comment: I think you need to make your project compatible so that it can use Jetpack Compose Library.

Comment: @MiroslavHýbler Yes, I'm using that in the library